# How to get only business days between two dates in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need help to count only business days (i.e excluding Saturday and Sunday ) between two dates in xslt 1.0

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible in XSLT... Depending on your XSLT processor,, you may be able to call custom functions, e.g. in [Xalan](http://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html) -- but your stylesheet won't be portable anymore

Comment: Thanks potame for you reply.
the problem is I am using this xslt in Oracle fusion middle-ware and including Xalan will be not possible.

Comment: Xalan may not be the only processor accepting this kind of extensions - it was but an example. Maybe Oracle XML processor provides similar features, refer to its technical documentation.

Comment: No, there is no need for extensions; there are pure XSLT 1.0 solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> count only business days (i.e excluding Saturday and Sunday ) between
>   two dates in xslt 1.0

If it can be assumed that the two given dates will **not** fall on Saturday or Sunday, you could use the method shown in the following example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <workdays>
            <xsl:call-template name="duration-in-workdays">
                <xsl:with-param name="start-date" select="'2015-04-02'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="end-date" select="'2015-04-08'" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </workdays>
    </output>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="duration-in-workdays">
    <!-- assumes start-date and end-date are both workdays -->
    <xsl:param name="start-date"/>
    <xsl:param name="end-date"/>
    <xsl:variable name="start">
        <xsl:call-template name="JDN">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="$start-date" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="end">
        <xsl:call-template name="JDN">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="$end-date" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="start-weekday" select="($start + 1) mod 7" />
    <xsl:variable name="end-weekday" select="($end + 1) mod 7" />
    <xsl:variable name="weeks" select="floor(($end - $start) div 7)" />
    <xsl:variable name="days" select="($end - $start) mod 7" />

    <xsl:value-of select="5 * $weeks + $days - 2*($start-weekday > $end-weekday)"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="JDN">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 9, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year + 4800 - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12*$a - 3"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$day + floor((153*$m + 2) div 5) + 365*$y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400) - 32045" />
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Caveat**: not tested thoroughly.

Comment: An XSLT 2.0/3.0 solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75731395/3016153

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="this:WorkDayDifference(xs:date('2014-05-01'),xs:date('2014-05-12'))"/>
    

</xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="this:WorkDayDifference">
        <xsl:param name="startDate" as="xs:date"/>
        <xsl:param name="endDate" as="xs:date"/>
        <xsl:variable name="endDateDay" select="this:day-of-week($endDate)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="days" select="days-from-duration($endDate - $startDate)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dow1" select="this:day-of-week($startDate)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dow2" select="this:day-of-week($endDate)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="weeks" select="xs:integer($days div 7)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="offset" select="if($dow2 ge $dow1) then if($endDateDay = 6 or $endDateDay = 0)then(-6)else(-5) else if($endDateDay = 6 or $endDateDay = 0)then(-1)else(0)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="wdays" select="sum((0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0)[position() ge $dow1 + 1 and position() le ($dow2 + 7)]) + $weeks * 5 + $offset + 1"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="number($wdays)"/>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:function name="this:day-of-week" as="xs:integer?" >
        <xsl:param name="date" as="xs:anyAtomicType?"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="if (empty($date)) then () else (xs:integer((xs:date($date) - xs:date('1901-01-06')) div xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')) mod 7)"/>
    </xsl:function>
```

Comment: The Above code can provide Business days between two days (excluding saturday, Sunday)
It works in XSLT 2.0

Business days (working days) between Jan 01, 2021 though Jan 15, 2021 == 11 days. 

Hope this helps for all.

Comment: This code can provide Business days between two days (excluding saturday, Sunday)
It works in XSLT 2.0

Business days (working days) between Jan 01, 2021 though Jan 15, 2021 == 11 days. 

Hope this helps for all.

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to put the explanation there, where it belongs, instead of in comments.