# Function to find difference between dates in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How can we find the difference between two dates in XSLT 1.0? Is there any build in function that we can use or do we have to use some bunch of code for it? Please help on the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any built in function that we can use ?

Well, in **XSLT 1.0**, there's **NO** such function which gives difference between two dates.

Though, there is a library of date-handling functions available at
*www.exslt.org*. Many of these are implemented in pure XSLT so they can be
used with any XSLT 1.0 processor.

> or do we have to use some bunch of code for it?

Yes. You need to implement it your way based on your requirements. Below are some great examples of finding the difference between two dates.

[Finding the difference between two dateTimes in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604414/finding-the-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-xslt)

[Finding the difference between 2 dates in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544762/finding-the-difference-between-2-dates-in-xslt)

[How to get only business days between two dates in xslt 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411708/how-to-get-only-business-days-between-two-dates-in-xslt-1-0)