# Count only business days (i.e excluding Saturday and Sunday ) between two dates in XSLT 3.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have 2 dates. Difference between them - 2 Bussines days.
How to create code on XSLT in ver 3.0 TO  calculate only business days (i.e excluding Saturday and Sunday )?

```
<date1>2023-03-10</date1>
<date2>2023-03-14</date2>
```

I have found this code. But its only working at xslt ver.1.0
[How to get only business days between two dates in xslt 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411708/how-to-get-only-business-days-between-two-dates-in-xslt-1-0)

And I would like to use XPATH to determine those dates in code. Because the dates can change, my task is for me to also pull the dates using Xpath

Comment: Why does the XSLT 1 (and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65877187/252228 seems to have an XSLT 2 solution as well) from the question you linked to not work with your XSLT 3 processor?

Comment: @MartinHonnen according that approach = my result is 4 days. but need 2 Bussines day. 
I mean this is not working at XSLT 3(

Comment: Anything that works in XSLT 1.0 will work in XSLT 3.0 as well. The XSLT 1.0 solution I posted in the linked question will return the expected result of 2 in your example. To get the dates from your input XML, simply point the `xsl:with-param` instructions to the relevant nodes in the XML.

Comment: Why 2? Isn't Friday, the 10th of March a business day, as Monday, the 13th, as Tuesday, the 14th?

Comment: Friday - 2023-03-10
Tuesday -2023-03-14.
Difference 4 Calendar Days. But If we use 2 BD to calculate the difference. There difference 2 bussines days!

Comment: @MartinHonnen It's a matter of convention: between today (Tuesday) and tomorrow (Wednesday) only 1 business day elapsed. If you count both days, then you will arrive at a 1 day difference between today and today.

Comment: @michael.hor257k nope. In my case( I can't receive correct dates) I also have issues 
line <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
The operator '-' is not defined for operands of type xs:integer and xs:string...

anyway look like that code realy don't works at xslt 3.0

Comment: @Iamfitz You're right, it requires backwards compatibility mode. I will try to post an XSLT 2.0/3.0 solution later today.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank you so much! It's really work. 
Can you please assist with using XPath's insted of variables for extracting dates values.
I mean I want to use this XPath somewhere in template. 
/input/range/start_date
/input/range/end_date
Is it possible to change xslt by using XPath? Where I should add it?

Comment: In my example, the context is already `range`. From this context, the expression `<xsl:value-of select="my:workdays-in-range(start_date, end_date)"/>` selects the the current range's `start_date` and `end_date `. You haven't posted a [mcve] so I don't know how exactly you need to adjust this.

Comment: @michael.hor257k can you please look at this one ? thanks!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75745415/how-to-create-code-on-xslt-in-ver-3-0-to-calculate-only-business-days-i-e-exclu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could look at it. Note that this assumes that the two given dates will not fall on Saturday or Sunday.

**XML**

```
<input>
    <range>
        <start_date>2023-03-10</start_date>
        <end_date>2023-03-14</end_date>
    </range>
    <range>
        <start_date>2023-03-10</start_date>
        <end_date>2023-03-15</end_date>
    </range>
    <range>
        <start_date>2023-03-10</start_date>
        <end_date>2023-03-16</end_date>
    </range>
    <range>
        <start_date>2023-03-10</start_date>
        <end_date>2023-03-17</end_date>
    </range>
    <range>
        <start_date>2023-03-10</start_date>
        <end_date>2023-03-20</end_date>
    </range>
</input>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="my:abs-week-number">
    <!-- weeks start on Sunday -->
    <xsl:param name="date" as="xs:date"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rataDie" select="days-from-duration($date - xs:date('0001-01-01')) + 1"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="$rataDie idiv 7"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="my:workdays-in-range">
    <xsl:param name="startDate" as="xs:date"/>
    <xsl:param name="endDate" as="xs:date"/>
    <!-- total days -->
    <xsl:variable name="total-days" select="days-from-duration($endDate - $startDate)"/>
    <!-- number of week boundaries (Sat|Sun) in range -->
    <xsl:variable name="weekends" select="my:abs-week-number($endDate) - my:abs-week-number($startDate)"/>
    <!-- total days minus weekend days -->
    <xsl:sequence select="$total-days - 2*$weekends" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/input">
   <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="range">
            <workdays start-date="{start_date}" end-date="{end_date}">
                <xsl:value-of select="my:workdays-in-range(start_date, end_date)"/>
            </workdays>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output>
   <workdays start-date="2023-03-10" end-date="2023-03-14">2</workdays>
   <workdays start-date="2023-03-10" end-date="2023-03-15">3</workdays>
   <workdays start-date="2023-03-10" end-date="2023-03-16">4</workdays>
   <workdays start-date="2023-03-10" end-date="2023-03-17">5</workdays>
   <workdays start-date="2023-03-10" end-date="2023-03-20">6</workdays>
</output>
```