# How to create code on XSLT in ver 3.0 to calculate only business days (i.e excluding Saturday and Sunday )?

Tags: xml, date, xslt, count, xslt-3.0

I have this code.

```
<trade>
    <exerciseDate>
        <adjustedDate>2023-03-10</adjustedDate>
    </exerciseDate>
    <cashPaymentDate>
        <adjustedDate>2023-03-14</adjustedDate>
    </cashPaymentDate>
    <currency>EUR</currency>
<effectiveDate>
    <adjustedDate>2023-03-14</adjustedDate>
    <dateAdjustments>
        <businessDayConvention>NONE</businessDayConvention>
    </dateAdjustments>
</effectiveDate>
<terminationDate>
    <unadjustedDate>2024-03-14</unadjustedDate>
        <dateAdjustments>
            <businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</businessDayConvention>
        </dateAdjustments>
</terminationDate>
</trade>
```

I would like to receive as XSLT (ver.3.0) only 1 value. Like below. The logic is Friday - **2023-03-10**,
Tuesday -**2023-03-14**. Difference **4** Calendar Days. But  I would like to receive value  2 ( that excluding Saturday and Sunday ) 'Business Days'

```
<workingDate>2</workingDate>
```

Can you please assist with using XPath's? I mean I want to use there XPath somewhere in template, that can calculate difference only in Business Days(**/trade/exerciseDate/adjustedDate** - 1st day and
**/trade/cashPaymentDate/adjustedDate** - 2nd day )

My goal is to create a template where I can only calculate the working dates that I have shown but using Xpath logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the expression:

```
my:workdays-in-range(/trade/exerciseDate/adjustedDate, trade/cashPaymentDate/adjustedDate )
```

after defining the necessary functions as shown in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75731395/3016153).